# Как сделать красивый дизайн?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Хочу научится модернизировать стандартные виджеты в Pyqt5. Вроде бы редизайн делается с помощью setStyleSheet, но я не нашел полный список команд. На сайте Qt лишь примеры. Для начала решил сделать как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая загвоздка: как сделать текст внутри QlineEdit. Чтоб при нажатии было вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше, как видно, ободок меняется при нажатии. Тоже не понятно как это настроить.
Буду благодарен за любую информацию)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За текст на заднем фоне отвечает функция [`setPlaceholderText(str)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop), а ободок можно сделать при помощи `qss`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color: #fff;}")
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.edit.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times New Roman", 14))
        self.edit.setPlaceholderText("Номер телефона")
        self.edit.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.edit.setStyleSheet("""
        QLineEdit{
            border: 1px solid #CCD6DD;
        }
        """)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Вход")
        self.button.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times New Roman", 12))

        self.button.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton{
            font-style: oblique;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 1px solid #1DA1F2;
            border-radius: 15px;
            color: #1DA1F2;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        """)
        self.button.setFixedSize(100, 40)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно по подробнее про qss.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov  ну проще говоря это `css` только встроенное в `qt`  можете [посмотреть ты документацию по нему](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: Ага понял. Спасибо